# Deleting the Bin folder to run an application

Tags: android, eclipse

Having problem here, some really annoying problem has started in my eclipse so please i need some advise on it .

when i make changes in my xml file they don't take effect when i run my application, this is really very odd, then i found that if i delete the contents in my bin folder except for the android Manifest.xml the changed application works  however the problem is that i have to do it all the time , even if there is a minor change in the application i have to delete the in folder and restart it and then everything is fine, this whole process is time consuming and really annoying and recently after i formatted my desktop and after i do the whole process that i mentioned  and then if i run the application i get an error like "Could not find xxx.apk". so Why does this happen ? and how do i solve this problem. Advices and support required.Thank YOu !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to force a full rebuild is to clean the project, then run the app - rather than deleting the bin/ folder.

Comment: PRoblem is solved thank you Chris, i had to update the build tools and now everything works fine . :)

Answer (score -1):

**Update: 2022**

Clearly things have changed in the last few years and you no longer have to delete your `bin/` folder. You can rebuild your project and try again

**2015**

I had the same problem, you shouldn't delete contents of the `bin/` folder. Delete the `bin/` folder itself. This should fix your errors!